# YuMe sdk for playing ads in ios device is not working

Tags: ios, sdk, initialization

I am using Yume sdk to play ads in the ios device.I followed the steps very carefully as shown in the samples.I have tried this multiple times but it is showing the error that 'Yume SDK is not initialized' every time I run it.Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Where did you get information to use the sdk and let me the location of the Samples